# Oracle Stored Procedure Name

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure in Oracle which uses a semicolon within the name. I'm using SQLPlus command line to create the stored procedure and it's complaining that the semicolon is an invalid character.

Is there an escape character to allow a stored procedure to contain a semi colon?

Thanks

Comment: What on Earth would _that_ be good for? Apart from creating chaos and mayhem, that is...

Comment: It's not at my request..

Comment: Do you work for the **PHB** from [Dilbert](http://www.dilbert.com)? I'm sorry to hear that, but I'd run from that place like it is on fire.

Comment: You should aware of naming, see some naming convention commonly used in oracle, http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6729304326802 and in yours it can be compiled with double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really must ......

```
create or replace procedure "!@#$%^&*();:<>?,./\|{}[]"( "@#$%;<>^^@@&" number )
is 
begin
  dbms_output.put_line( 'Output is ' || "@#$%;<>^^@@&" );
end;
/

exec "!@#$%^&*();:<>?,./\|{}[]"( 2 );

run -------
Output is 2
```

Hint: surround the procedure name with quotation marks.

Comment: +1 for answering the Q, but.... whenever I see strings like !@#$%... I think the code is swearing. Which is what I'd be doing if I saw these characters being used in identifiers and I was the kind of person who swears!

Comment: Excuse me, I am not native english speaker, and I am not quite sure what does "swear" mean, I hope I didn't offend you, if yes then I'am very sorry, it wasn't my intent to be rude.

Comment: Oh no @kordirko, I was just joking - there was nothing offensive in your answer, I'm just easily amused and have a quirky sense of humour :)